# Why is the return for number to high or to low is incorrect in my guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

When my game returns the the computers answer for whether its number is too high or too low it will say that the number is to high but the actual number is higher. For example, it will say computer guessed 7 which is too high and the number is 10. 
The user input for option to is randomly changing numbers as well. So this could be linked to the previously stated issue.

```
"""
    Displays the main menu then reads in the user choice.
    Depending on user choice program may have user guess a number
    generated by the computer, computer guesses a number given by user,
    or user exits program.
    """

def main():
    display_menu()
    option = int(input("Enter a menu option: "))

    if option == 1:
        import random
        number = random.randint(1,10)
        counter = 0

        while True:
            try:        
                guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
                guess = int(guess)
                print()
                if guess < 1 or guess > 10:
                    raise ValueError()
                counter += 1
                if guess > number:
                    print("Too high.")
                    print()
                elif guess < number:
                    print("Too low.")
                    print()
                else:
                    print("You guessed it!")
                    print("You guessed the number in", counter, "attempts!")
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print(guess, "is not a valid guess")
                print()
    """
    Option 2., User enters a number for the computer to guess.
    Computer guesses a number within the range given.
    Outputs computer guesses and number of guesses until computer gets
    the correct number.
    """

    if option == 2:
        import random
        print("Computer guess my number")
        print()

        while True:
            try:
                my_num = input("Enter a number betrween 1 and 10 for the computer to guess: ")
                my_num = int(my_num)
                print()

                counter = 1
                comp = random.randint(1,10)

                if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                    raise ValueError()

                if comp > my_num:
                    print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")
                    comp = random.randint(1,10)

                elif comp < my_num:
                    print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")
                    comp = random.randint(1,10)


                print("Computer the right number!" , comp)
                print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(my_num, "is not a valid guess")
                print()

    if option == 3:
        print("Goodbye")

"""
    Defines menue and user choices.
    """

def display_menu():
    print("Welcome to my Guesss the Number Program!")
    print("1. You guess the number")
    print("2. You type a number and see if the computer can guess it.")
    print("3. Exit")
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code block

```
            if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                raise ValueError()

            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)


            print("Computer the right number!" , comp)
            print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")
            break
```

seems to be the cause of your issue (although it's not exactly what you describe). No matter what happens, it will always say the computer got the correct number. You should add an else like such:

```
            if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                raise ValueError()

            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)

            else:
                print("Computer the right number!" , comp)
                print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")
                break
```

Furthermore, the start of the block of code also needs some fixing. The code will ask you to fill in a new number for every cycle **and** the counter needs to be updated every cycle. If you implement this, the start of the code ends up looking something like this:

```
if option == 2:
    import random
    print("Computer guess my number")
    print()
    my_num = input("Enter a number betrween 1 and 10 for the computer to guess: ")
    my_num = int(my_num)
    counter = 1

    while True:
        try:
            counter += 1
            print()

            comp = random.randint(1,10)
```

This also means this:

```
            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")
                comp = random.randint(1,10)
```

Can be changed to:

```
            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low")
```

Because the computer will make a new guess anyway.

**FYI I recommend doing all your imports at the top of your file, not halfway through the code.**

Also, it's 'too high/low' not 'to high/low' ;)

Comment: i added the else: but it stops the computers guess after the first guess.

Comment: @TNieuwenhuis you will also want to move the place where you ask for my number outside of the while loop

Comment: i made the suggested changes Nathan but now my validation error inst working if i enter a letter or number outside the range.

Comment: @TNieuwenhuis and what could be the cause of that?

Answer (score 0):

> The user input for option to is randomly changing.

```
        if comp > my_num:
            print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")
            comp = random.randint(1,10)
```

because of the third line generating a new random number.

```
while True:
    try:
```

the loop exited because the "try" block succeed,not because the guess was right.

```
counter = 1
```

the counter should be instanced then incremented, otherwise it will remain at zero.

Working example after few changes :

```
"""
    Displays the main menu then reads in the user choice.
    Depending on user choice program may have user guess a number
    generated by the computer, computer guesses a number given by user,
    or user exits program.
    """
import sys
import random

def main():
    display_menu()
    option = int(input("Enter a menu option: "))

    if option == 1:            
        number = random.randint(1,10)
        counter = 0

        while True:
            try:        
                guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
                guess = int(guess)
                print()
                if guess < 1 or guess > 10:
                    raise ValueError()
                counter += 1
                if guess > number:
                    print("Too high.")
                    print()
                elif guess < number:
                    print("Too low.")
                    print()
                else:
                    print("You guessed it!")
                    print("You guessed the number in", counter, "attempts!")
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print(guess, "is not a valid guess")
                print()
    """
    Option 2., User enters a number for the computer to guess.
    Computer guesses a number within the range given.
    Outputs computer guesses and number of guesses until computer gets
    the correct number.
    """

    if option == 2:
        print("Computer guess my number")
        print()


        my_num = input("Enter a number betrween 1 and 10 for the computer to guess: \n")
        my_num = int(my_num)
        comp = 0
        counter = 0
        while comp != my_num:

            counter += 1
            comp = random.randint(1,10)

            if my_num < 1 or my_num > 10:
                print(my_num, "is not a valid guess")
                sys.exit(0)


            if comp > my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to High")

            elif comp < my_num:
                print("Computer guessed", comp,"to Low ")


        print("Computer the right number!" , comp)
        print("Computer guessed the right number in", counter, "attempts!")


    if option == 3:
        print("Goodbye")

"""
    Defines menue and user choices.
    """

def display_menu():
    print("Welcome to my Guesss the Number Program!")
    print("1. You guess the number")
    print("2. You type a number and see if the computer can guess it.")
    print("3. Exit")
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```